# Is it useful to set the policies to DROP for all tables in Iptables?

Tags: security, iptables, hardening

I use `iptables` to secure my server. The default policies for all **chains** in the `filter` table have been set to **DROP**

```
# iptables -t filter -L | grep -i \ (policy
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
```

I wonder if it is useful **to also set the policies to DROP** for `mangle`, `raw` and `security` tables *(not `nat` table because it does not work)*
in order to more secure the server ?

And of course duplicate the access rules for each tables setted to DROP

Comment: Drop is not better than reject and if you use either you can lock yourself out if you flush the tables. I just use accept and last rule is reject. See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't set these policies on the other tables to `DROP`, these tables are not meant to filter.

You may want to try it on a local machine, where you have local access even if you block the network.